# Uninstall Magento 2.3 module (including database data) Getting Exceptions Error

Tags: magento2, database, uninstall-module

I am trying to uninstall some modules in my Magento 2.3.1, I followed the following steps:

```
Remove the module Vendor_% from app\etc\config.php
Drop module tables or columns from database, please check app\code\Vendor\Module\Setup folder for more information
Remove the folder app\code\vendor/%
Remove module configuration settings from core_config_data table by running the following query
    DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'vendor%';
Remove module from setup_module table by running the following query
    DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module LIKE 'vendor_%';
SSH Server
    php bin/magento cache:clean
    php bin/magento cache:flush
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
    php bin/magento setup:di:compile
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
    php bin/magento indexer:reindex
    php bin/magento cache:clean
    php bin/magento cache:flush
```

The problem is that after doing all this I receive the following error message:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix this problem?

**UPDATE 1**

Now I have the following error, but nothing appears in table eav_attribute, any idea of ​​how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Delete generated folder, clear cache and run "bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated" and let me know if that works. Please cross verify that no other module was dependent on the module you uninstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run below query in MySQL its issue comming due to attribute exist in database.

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `backend_model` LIKE 'Rokanthemes\Categorytab\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Thumbnailimage'
```

Then delete that row it will fixed issue.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: Hi, I have another error (you can see my update in my question), but nothing appears in table eav_attribute, any idea of ​​how to fix it?

Comment: @Despotars check this in same table with frontend_model column

Comment: ok thanks! Finally there were more rows that can be detected by the source_model column. Thank you very much again! :)